# How can I avoid nested if statements?

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to avoid nested if statements if you need to check for the length of both checks?

```
if (checkData.audience.length) {
  checkData.audience.forEach((element: CheckData) => {
    if(element.name.length > 0) {
      console.log('check two');
    }
  });
}
```

it's not returning anything, so I can not make use of the reverse check.

How can I avoid the nested if statements in this case?

Comment: *it's not returning anything, so I can not make use of the reverse check*, What is not returning anything?

Comment: As long as `checkData.audience` is not `null` or `undefined`, you don't need to check its length before calling `forEach`. `Array#forEach` will happily ignore an empty array.

Comment: Following what @DM said, you can use `for ... of ...` too...

Comment: @AlexSp3 the if statement doesn't return a value. 

if it was returning a value I can handle this with the reverse check eg. `!checkData`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by removing the check for `checkData.audience.length`
`forEach` is ignoring an empty array.

Comment: `forEach` is iterating over an empty array, which results in 0 iterations. Which is essentially the same as ignoring the array (in this context), but I would personally not use the term "ignore" here. Say you are a teacher and have a list of students of which their presence must be validated. Normally you would call out a name, the student would respond with "check" or "present". Now imagine the list of students being empty. You don't "ignore" the list. You take the list and have a look at it. Since it's empty you're essentially immediately done.